# Connect to Firebase failed with assistant in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, socket-timeout-exception

I want to connect my app to firebase and for that I am doing it by Firebase Assistant in android studio.

When I click on connect to firebase the following error is shown:

> Firebase: Connect to Firebase failed. Please check your internet connection and try again. If errors persist, you can connect manually at https://console.firebase.google.com
>   SocketTimeoutException: Could not obtain an OAuth2 access token.: connect timed out

Note: I am properly connected with internet and my android studio is updated.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check ur firebase console once, It happens that the  project gets created in firebase console but still it shows the error, If it is so, then go to project settings of that project and add the package name of the project in it, and then download the google-services.json file,add the json file in root project directory. Add the necessary dependencies for the feature u want to use from firebase assistant. U are all set to use firebase now!!..Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

**This is happening because you have exceeded your limits of making new projects in Firebase Console.**

This is how your console window will look like when you try to make a new project from Firebase Console itself.

[image: This is how your console window will look like when you try to make a new project from Firebase Console itself.]

It says:

> You've reached the project limit for your account. You can add Firebase to an existing project or request an increased limit.

Solution:

1) One solution is to add your application in a pre-built project of yours (if you haven't deleted all of your project and if you haven't exceeded your app limits)

2) The second solution is to **REQUEST AN INCREASE** in your project limits by clicking on the option below the error.

After requesting for an increase and giving a good reason for why you want an increase, you will get your increased projects limit soon and then you will be able to explore unmatchable features of the great Firebase again.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the Firebase Assistant from the sidebar is not using the proxy settings from Android Studio. So the Firebase Assistant might fail even if the Android Studio can reach the internet.

Didn't find the reason but connecting to a mobile hotspot solved the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This is wired but my issue was solved when I made sure I was signed into the same Google account in the browser and Android studio :

1. Google Play Console
2. Google Developer Console
3. Firebase Console

Comment: How to check that it is the same Google account in Android Studio?

Answer (score -2):

Please use the latest library for firebase

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'**

please follow this guide if counter another issue

**https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup**

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.